# Access and set_state during quantum computation simulation in cirq

Tags: programming, cirq

The [documentation](https://quantumai.google/cirq/simulation#stepping_through_a_circuit) for Cirq mentions the possibility to step through a circuit's moments, and access the exact wavefunction via `step.state_vector()`, and edit set it via `step.set_state()`. In the API documentation, neither function is documented. While the former seems to work anyway, the latter (setting the state) gives an AttributeError. I am using Cirq 0.9.1.

How can I change the wavefunction used for the next moment simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a bug in the docs, the method is `set_state_vector()` - I opened https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/3623.

The methods are only available on the `SparseSimulatorStep` which is the default simulator in Cirq.

They are available in the API docs though set_state_vector has no docstring:

- [state_vector()](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/sim/SparseSimulatorStep?hl=en#state_vector)
- [set_state_vector()](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/sim/SparseSimulatorStep?hl=en#set_state_vector)